# Using Pointer as Key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, pointers, dictionary

I have a set of (totally) ordered objects of class `OrderedObject`

```
public class OrderedObject {
    public int ord;        // ordinal number
}
```

They have a field `ord`of type `int` that is unique for each object and represents their ordinal number. Nonetheless the value of `ord` can vary for each object. I would like to store the objects in a `Dictionary<int*, OrderedObject>` such that the key (asterisk stands for pointer to `int`, not sure how to achieve that with C#, but this is NOT my question) points to the ordinal number of the value object and changes automatically with the latter. **Is that somehow possible?**

For those who think my undertaking makes little sense: The background is that for now the ordinal number is a natural number represented by an integer, but later it will be replaced by another `OrderedObject` where ordering works slightly different from ordering the natural numbers.

Comment: If the ints are unique, why not map them by just `ord`?

Comment: You should not be using pointers.

Comment: @SLaks Even if he use, I guess he'll not be able to create a `Dictionary<int*, OrderedObject>`.

Comment: `ord` should not be a part of `OrderedObject`. You could store instance of `Dictinary` to which `OrderedObject` belongs (sort of *parent* property for list item) if you want to get that number, but there is no sense for it to be *inside*.

Comment: This is not possible actually. And in spite of your disclaimer at the end of your question: Your requirement still doesn't make any sense. Just because a `Dictionary` by definition is not ordered. If you want to order something, use and sort a `List`.

Comment: If ordering on these objects works differently, you might implement a custom comparer and use ordinary collections

Comment: Not an option, the key must be stable.  You'll need to derive your own class from KeyedCollection, the ChangeItemKey() method is crucial.

Comment: @Sinatr `ord` has to be part of the object. The objects represent vertices of a graph and hold their adjacent vertices in private collections. They can interact with each other and event create new objects when required. During the interaction `ord` changes. In my dictionary I only want to store a small subset of all present vertices. If two such vertices with `ord=1` and `ord=2` swap their order, the keys in my dictionary should update automatically and I still can access the new "first" element by index 1 and get the former 2nd element.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a key in any dictionary has to be unique so you wont be able to swap by changing one key after the other. in this case you have to implement this differently. but as long as you have unique keys at all times you can do the following:

```
class ReorderingDictionary : IDictionary<int, OrderItem>
    {

        private SortedList<int, OrderItem> sortedList = new SortedList<int, OrderItem>();

        public void Add(int key, OrderItem value)
        {
            value.IneedToBeReordered += value_IneedToBeReordered;
            sortedList.Add(key, value);
        }

        void value_IneedToBeReordered(object sender, ReOrderMeEventArgs e)
        {
            sortedList.Remove(e.OldKey);
            OrderItem item = (OrderItem)sender;
            sortedList.Add(item.Ord, item);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(int key)
        {
            return sortedList.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public ICollection<int> Keys
        {
            get { return sortedList.Keys; }
        }

        public bool Remove(int key)
        {
            return sortedList.Remove(key);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(int key, out OrderItem value)
        {
            return sortedList.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        public ICollection<OrderItem> Values
        {
            get { return sortedList.Values; }
        }

        public OrderItem this[int key]
        {
            get
            {
                return sortedList[key];
            }
            set
            {
                sortedList[key] = value;
            }
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<int, OrderItem> item)
        {
            item.Value.IneedToBeReordered += value_IneedToBeReordered;
            sortedList.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            sortedList.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<int, OrderItem> item)
        {
            return sortedList.ContainsKey(item.Key) && sortedList[item.Key] == item.Value;
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<int, OrderItem>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return sortedList.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<int, OrderItem> item)
        {
            return sortedList.Remove(item.Key);
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, OrderItem>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return sortedList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return sortedList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }


    class OrderItem
    {
        private int ord;

        public int Ord
        {
            get { return ord; }
            set
            {
                int oldKey = ord;
                ord = value;
                if (IneedToBeReordered != null)
                {
                    IneedToBeReordered(this, new ReOrderMeEventArgs(oldKey));
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ReOrderMeEventArgs> IneedToBeReordered;
    }

    class ReOrderMeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int OldKey { get; private set; }

        public ReOrderMeEventArgs(int oldKey)
        {
            this.OldKey = oldKey;
        }
    }
```